# Dimension of holomorphic vector fields on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry

Let $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ act on $\mathbb{P}^1$ by $g([v]) = [gv]$. Let $\Gamma(T\mathbb{P}^1)$ be the space of sections on $T\mathbb{P}^1$. Find its the dimension and show it is isomorphic to the adjoint representation.

The dimension is supposedly $3$ with every vector field of the form $p(t)\frac{d}{dt}$ where $t$ is the affine coordinate and deg $p(t) \leq 2$. I do not know how they obtained the upper limit of the degree.

Comment: Look in coordinates around $\infty$. Rewrite your vector field and see when it’ll be holomorphic at $\infty$.

Comment: I asked a related question [not long ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389163/holomorphic-tangent-bundle-over-projective-line). Maybe the answer will be of help. The answer and comments implemented the above hint.

Comment: Yeah this helps a lot. I got three dimensions from the actions of H, E and F in $sl(2)$, just need to show that's all there is.