# Holomorphic tangent bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-space, tangent-bundle

> Denote the universal bundle of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ by $U$, the dual bundle by $H$. Prove that the Holomorphic tangent bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is isomorphic to $H\otimes H$, and calculate the dimension of the space of global holomorphic sections(i.e. holomorphic vector fields).

I'm new on complex geometry. There are some questions similar to mine on MSE and I am trying to understand some of them. I wonder is there a direct proof or some reference for my question.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you link the questions you are trying to understand? It might be more helpful for you to reference them in an answer.

Comment: The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389163/holomorphic-tangent-bundle-over-projective-line) has a self-contained calculation and reference for the space of sections once you know the tangent bundle is $\mathcal{O}(2)$. <> The classical calculation for $T\mathbf{P}^1=\mathcal{O}(2)$ is to use the holomorphic atlas induced by $w = 1/z$ and calculate the transition from $\partial/\partial z$ to $\partial/\partial w$.

Comment: Thanks. And is there a more detailed reference for $T\mathbf{P}^1=\mathcal{O}(2)$ you mentioned?